# jQuery - *variable* is not defined

Tags: jquery, scope, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was wondering if anyone could help clear up this issue I am having.

I have been trying all morning to get a Facebook share button to work with dynamic parameters unique to the video that was being played on the page at the time.

I think the following should work but I am getting the error: `share_title` is not defined.

I then tried setting the contents of a div to the contents of the ajax response and then setting the `params` variable to the contents of that div so that the variables would be accessible within the `FB.ui` function but that didn't seem to work either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$('.share_button').live('click', function(e){
    $('#player').fadeOut('slow');
    var share_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/youtube.php',
        data: 'share='+ share_id,
        success: function(data) {
            //$('#params').html(data);
            //params = $('#params').html();
            param = data.split('--');
            share_title = param[0];
            share_description = param[1];
            share_picture = param[2];
            share_views = param[3];
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui(
    {       
        method: 'feed',
        name: share_title,
        link: 'http://www.facebook.com',
        picture: share_picture,
        caption: share_views,
        description: share_description
    },
    function(response) {
        $('#player').show('slow');     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `FB.ui` call in the AJAX callback.

```
$('.share_button').live('click', function(e) {
    $('#player').fadeOut('slow');
    var share_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/youtube.php',
        data: 'share=' + share_id,
        success: function(data) {
            //$('#params').html(data);
            //params = $('#params').html();
            param = data.split('--');
            share_title = param[0];
            share_description = param[1];
            share_picture = param[2];
            share_views = param[3];

            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: share_title,
                link: 'http://www.facebook.com',
                picture: share_picture,
                caption: share_views,
                description: share_description
            }, function(response) {
                $('#player').show('slow');
            });
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

AJAX is asynchronous. The call to `$.ajax` returns *before* the HTTP request has completed (i.e. before the `success` callback has executed), and the program flow continues. This means that, in this situation;

1. Your *initiating* the AJAX request via `$.ajax`
2. You're calling `e.preventDefault()`
3. You're calling `FB.ui`
4. *Sometime* later, the AJAX request completes, and the `share_title` is populated.

FYI, you should also declare you're variables; otherwise you're making them [implicit globals, which are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript);

```
$('.share_button').live('click', function(e) {
    $('#player').fadeOut('slow');
    var share_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var share_title;
    var share_... // do all your other share_*'s here as well.

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/youtube.php',
        data: 'share=' + share_id,
        success: function(data) {
            //$('#params').html(data);
            //params = $('#params').html();
            param = data.split('--');
            share_title = param[0];
            share_description = param[1];
            share_picture = param[2];
            share_views = param[3];

            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: share_title,
                link: 'http://www.facebook.com',
                picture: share_picture,
                caption: share_views,
                description: share_description
            }, function(response) {
                $('#player').show('slow');
            });
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: ah, that makes sense now. thanks so much for your help. I was going nuts! reasons the variables weren't declared as `vars` was because I was seeing if it made any difference if I took it out but don't need to worry about that now. Great answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `$.ajax` call is asynchronous. You should make the call to `FB.ui` in the `success` callback, which is called when the AJAX request has succeeded:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/youtube.php',
    data: 'share='+ share_id,
    success: function(data) {
        param = data.split('--');
        share_title = param[0];
        share_description = param[1];
        share_picture = param[2];
        share_views = param[3];

        FB.ui({       
            method: 'feed',
            name: share_title,
            link: 'http://www.facebook.com',
            picture: share_picture,
            caption: share_views,
            description: share_description
        },
        function(response) {
            $('#player').show('slow');     
        });
    }
});
```